# Использование свойств потомка через родителя java

Tags: java, наследование, преобразование-типов

Есть 2 класса:

```
public class Parent {
    String parentString;
    public Parent() {}
    public Parent(String parentString) {
        this.parentString = parentString;
    }
}

public class Child  extends Parent{
    private String childString;
    public Child() {}
    public Child(String childString) {
        this.childString = childString;
    }
    public String getChildString() {
        return childString;
    }
}
```

И вот такой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Child c = new Child("child");
    method(c);
}

public static void method(Parent p) {
    Child c = (Child) p;
    System.out.println(c.getChildString());
}
```

Вопрос: насколько такой код корректен? Мы как параметр отправляем ссылку на объект в памяти, всегда ли я смогу скастить родителя к наследнику, если отправляю наследника? Понимаю, что если отправить родителя, то будет Exception, это я отловлю.

Ред: метод универсален, исправить сигнатуру не могу(это библиотека, используемая не только моим проектом), но могу дописать код в сам метод, который не будет ломать функциональность.

Ред2: Классы родителя и потомка редактировать крайне проблемно и не всегда возможно. Родителя, скорее всего, править вообще не дадут.

Comment: Такой подход, вообще не корректен, зачем вообще передавать `Parent` в метод. 
Смените на `Child` и дело с концом.

Comment: Сделал апдейт вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Технически так можно, но некрасиво. Некрасиво в том смысле, что не ложится в общую концепцию ООП и Java  в частности. По идее надо делать примерно так:

```
public class Parent {
    String parentString;
    public Parent() {}
    public Parent(String parentString) {
        this.parentString = parentString;
    }
    public String getChildString() {return null;} //можно просто объявить abstract
}

public class Child  extends Parent{
    private String childString;
    public Child() {}
    public Child(String childString) {
        this.childString = childString;
    }
    
    @Overrides
    public String getChildString() {
        return childString;
    }
}
```

Если позволяют обстоятельства то `Parent` можно объявить абстрактным.

В таком случае, никаких дурацких кастов не возникает:

```
public static void method(Parent p) {
    System.out.println(p.getChildString());
}
```

Comment: К сожалению и родитель и ребенок от меня мало зависят, мне туда очень проблемно добавить что то свое, так как многие другие системы аффектятся. В целом мне только значение поля нужно, если его нет, то пойду по дефолтному пути